# LinqToXml; query where attribute does not exist

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

Is there syntax to state where attribute does not exist?

```
    Dim xe As XElement = _
    <xml>
        <el att1="ABC" att2="XYZ"/>
        <el att1="ABC"/>
        <el/>
    </xml>

    Dim xe2 As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    xe2 = From c In xe.<el> Where c.@att1 = "ABC" And DoesNotExist(c.@att2)

    'Return: <el att1="ABC"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xe2 = From c In xe.<el> Where c.@att1 = "ABC" And c.@att2 Is Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.@att2)`.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but gave the correct answer to NoAlias as it feels closer to implementation.